# Integral; How is this step done?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I've been attempting several other integrals and have a hit a massive wall in terms of this question:

$$\int\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}dx$$

I tried looking into substitutions to perform but couldn't find any useful ones on my own, so after consulting an online calculator, the following method was used:
[image]

How is this performed? I cannot understand how "adding 0" in the numerator yields the fraction $\int(\frac{4}{x^2-4}+1)dx$. Can anyone help shed light on this? I feel like it's very basic, but I haven't a clue how it was done :S

Comment: $\frac {x^2-4+4}{x^2-4}=\frac {x^2-4}{x^2-4}+\frac 4{x^2-4}$.

Comment: Ah, so it was a simple algebra thing, thank you so very much for stepping it out :D

Comment: @PixelRain Did you try going in the other direction, adding $1$ and $4/(x^2 - 4)$ and seeing what you got?

Comment: You can also do this by long-division of polynomials.  In general, when you have an _improper_ rational expression, you should re-write it as a polynomial plus a proper rational expression.

Comment: You often want to build a "copy" of some multiple of the denominator in the numerator by adding and subtracting the same term(s), so the copy can divide out later. So $$\frac{x^2}{\boxed{x^2-4}}=\frac{\boxed{x^2-4} + 4}{x^2-4}=\frac{x^2-4}{x^2-4}+\frac{4}{x^2-4} = 1+\frac{4}{x^2-4}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, consider the general way of adding fractions together
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad+bc}{db}\, \qquad (b, d) \neq 0$$

The answer given considers
\begin{align}
1+\frac{4}{x^{2}-4} &= \frac{1}{1}+\frac{4}{x^{2}-4} \\
&= \frac{(1)(x^{2}-4)+4(1)}{(1)(x^{2}-4)} \\
&= \frac{x^{2}-4+4}{x^{2}-4} \\
&= \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}-4}\, \qquad (\text{QED})
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps $$\int  \frac { x^{ 2 } }{ x^{ 2 }-4 } dx=\int  \frac { x^{ 2 }-4+4 }{ x^{ 2 }-4 } dx=\int  \left( \frac { x^{ 2 }-4 }{ x^{ 2 }-4 } +\frac { 4 }{ x^{ 2 }-4 }  \right) dx=\\ =\int { \left( 1+\frac { 4 }{ x^{ 2 }-4 }  \right) dx= } \int { dx } +4\int { \frac { dx }{ { x }^{ 2 }-4 }  } $$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $$\frac{x^2}{x^2-4}=\frac{x^2-4+4}{x^2-4}=1+\frac{4}{x^2-4}=1+\frac{4}{(x-2)(x+2)}$$

Comment: Why don't you continue by writing that last $4$ in the numerator in the form
$$4=(x+2)-(x-2)?$$

Comment: yes this can be done

Comment: or $$\frac{4}{x^2-4}=\frac{A}{x-4}+\frac{B}{x+4}$$